# Calculation mode in pandas rolling window

Tags: python, pandas, statistics, rolling-computation

I am trying to calculate the mode of data by column within a rolling window.

`df['data_mode'] = group_df[col].rolling(window=window, min_periods=0).apply(lambda x: mode(x)[0][0], raw=True)`

I received:

`ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().`

I checked - this `mode(x)[0][0]` works with column data (not in DataFrame) correctly. Returns numbers.

Please tell me how to fix it.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please take the time to read this post on [how to provide a great pandas example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples) as well as how to provide a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and revise your question accordingly. These tips on [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) may also be useful.

Answer (score 0):

Have u tried mode with this?

```
.apply(lambda x: mode(x)[0])
```

Bwt easier to solve if you give the example df.